# I can not change the title of Jbutton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I can change the location of a JButton, but I can not change the title.  Is it possible that the java file is corrupted? How come I can't change the title while changing the location? I use Eclipse...

[image: The first code]
[image: The frame with JButton]
[image: The Changed code]
[image: The frame with JButton]

Comment: You set the width & height of the button to 15 pixels each, there's no way that text fits into that size, so it's "abbreviated".

Comment: Something not right with the bounds, you might want to refer this example: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-jbutton

Comment: Don't post images of your code. Post actual code in the forum in the form of an [mre].

Comment: Thank you Joachim, it's all about tha abbrevation... I thought that the change I made to the button did not happen because I used three dots for the settings button text. So I didn't notice. I was about to go crazy. Thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

The width of the button is too short to display the title (15 pixels). As a fallback, the `…` is shown.

In addition, I highly recommend not to use the `setBounds` method directly. Take a look at a Java Swing tutorial on Youtube, Vimeo, Udemy, or as a book. You will learn how to create a user interface with layout managers. You won't have these kinds of problems then.

You might want to consider learning JavaFX instead because Swing is end of life.